# Como eu apresento 3 jogadores de uma equipa?

Tags: php

Eu Desejo apresentar 3 jogadores que sao da mesma equipa mas, para isso eu quero que so apareça o nome da equipa uma vez.

```
$query = "SELECT distinct nometeam from jogador";

$dados = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysql_error());

$linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dados);

$total = mysqli_num_rows($dados);
?>

<center>

<table class = "tabela" style="width:100%" border="0" bgcolor="white" style="text-align:center;">  

    <tr> 
        <td allign = 'left'><b> Nome da Equipa </b></td>

        <td allign = 'center'><b> Nome do Jogador </b></td>

        <td allign = 'center' colspan = '3'><b> Pontuação do Jogador </b></td>

    </tr>

     <?php
     if($total){ do {

        $query1 = "SELECT * from `jogador`, `pontos` WHERE `nometeam` = '".$linha['nometeam']."'" ;

        $dados1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query1);

        $linha1 = mysqli_fetch_array($dados1);      
    ?>

    <tr>        
        <td><?php echo $linha['nometeam'] ?></td>

        <td><?php echo $linha1['nome'] ?><td>

        <td><?php echo $linha1['pontos'] ?></td>
    </tr>

    <?php
         }while($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dados));}
    ?>  


</table>

</center>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: fica muito difícil ajudar sem conhecer a estrutura das tabelas nem ver um exemplo de dados

Comment: ok. Jogador - codj, nome, nometeam, datanasc, emai, contacto, genero. Os dados sao dados de teste mesmo

Comment: Sugiro que remova o css da pergunta, e que se foque no problema que será relativo ao php e/ou banco de dados

Comment: o css e so uma parte estética do site

Comment: Sim eu sei, mais são mais coisas na pergunta que acabam por encher e "distrair" quem tenta perceber o seu problema. O mesmo se aplica a etiquetas de `<title>` entre outras. Quanto mais conseguir minimizar a sua questão ao que realmente interessa melhor. Isso aqui na nossa rede tem um nome que é um [Exemplo mínimo, completo e verificavel do problema](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Pode ir ver agora, eu minimizei o que consegui

Comment: tenta agrupar pelo nome da equipa, por exemplo:
`select nometeam, nome from jogador, pontos WHERE nometeam = '".$linha['nometeam']."' group by nometeam, nome"`

Comment: Se o nome da equipe é uma coluna na tabela, como exatamente deseja exibir apenas uma vez? Seria somente na primeira linha das 3?

Comment: O que eu preciso é que me seja apresentado 3 jogadores por 1 equipa